# How to join pyspark dataframes on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have below pyspark dataframe

```
id|code|unit|name |rate |parameters
A |123 |ARC |name1|     |unit,rate,name
A |124 |FBC |name2|rate1|rate,name
B |125 |CDC |     |rate2|unit
B |126 |ARC |     |     |unit,rate,name
C |127 |ARB |     |     |
```

and I want to join this with another pyspark dataframe with headers `unit|rate|name|result`

each row of first dataframe will be joined on columns mentioned in parameters column.

This is what I have tried :

```
params = sqlContext.sql('Select distinct parameters from firstDFtable')
paramspandas = params.toPandas()

for i in range(len(paramspandas .index)):
    df = firstDF.where(firstDF.params=paramspandas(i,parameters))
    ### now form query based on values in parameter column and join

###At the end of for loop concat all dataframes in one
```

In above approach I am splitting first dataframe on the basis of parameters column and then performing joins on each dataframe separately. After that I am concatinating all dataframes. That seems to be a bit complicated. Is there a better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: And `clm1` corresponds to what column in the first DF? The same for `clm2` and `clm3`.

Comment: clm1,clm2,clm3 are present in second dataframe only. No relation with first dataframe.

Comment: And how do you want join the first row for example ? Can you add an example of output please?

Comment: extremely sorry. you are right. I have updated the question with the relation.

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have added the code now. Thanks